# TikZ: How to place two decorations in opposite directions

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I use TikZ to create the following image?

[image]

I created this image with the following code, took a screenshot of the output, and then modified the screenshot by erasing the edge inside the left diamond.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,node distance=1.4cm,semithick]
  \node [draw, fill, shape=circle] (0)  {};
  \node [draw, fill, shape=circle] (1) [right of=0] {};
  \path (1) edge[bend left,postaction={decorate, decoration={
                  markings,
                  mark=at position 0.99 with {\arrow[>=diamond,white] {>}; },
                  mark=at position 0.99 with {\arrow[>=open diamond]  {>}; } } }] (0)
        (0) edge[bend right,postaction={decorate, decoration={
                  markings,
                  mark=at position 0.99 with {\arrow[>=diamond,white] {>}; },
                  mark=at position 0.99 with {\arrow[>=open diamond]  {>}; } } }] (1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,node distance=1.4cm,semithick]
  \node [draw, fill, shape=circle] (0)  {};
  \node [draw, fill, shape=circle] (1) [right of=0] {};
  \path (1) edge[bend left,postaction={decorate, decoration={
                  markings,
                  mark=at position 0.99 with {\arrow{diamond[fill=white]}; },
                  mark=at position 0.01 with {\arrowreversed{diamond[fill=white]}} } }] (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or maybe this is the problem.  If I change `\arrowreversed` back to `\arrow`, it doesn't compile because it doesn't like `diamond[fill=white]`. Why is that?

Comment: Even if I start with my code and just change `\arrow` to `\arrowreversed`, the output is not correct. What a disaster this turning out to be.

Comment: @TysonWilliams No worries. Probably you don't have TikZ 3.00. Put somewhere in the body of the document `\pgfversion` to see what you have

Comment: I have 2.10.  I plan to update this summer, so I will just accept your answer and be patient until it will work for me :)